# 404 Error while Sync Server in SAAS

Tags: odoo, saas, saaskit

I am having problem while i sync the server and this type of error message is displayed.

[image]

[image]

i am using apache2 server

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName o9.local
ServerAlias *.o9.local
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8097/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8097/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyErrorOverride Off
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/webclient-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/webclient-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

can you help me to find out the solution ?